# SharedPreferences isn't saving my data

Tags: java, android

So in my game I'm making, I'm using SharedPreferences to save my data, however it's not saving my data or restoring it (either or both). (And yes I know getting using `double.valueOf()` is inefficient but that's not the problem now)

Here's my onCreate (where I get all the saved data)

```
       public int hasPlayed = 0;
public double $money;
public int $isonmainpage = 1;
Random random = new Random();
public int $cantafford = 0;
public double $employertimer;
public double $employercounter;

public double $employeeupgrade1earnings;
public double $employeeupgrade1cost = 1;
public double $employeeupgrade1level;


public double $employerupgrade1level;
public double $employerupgrade1earnings;
public double $employerupgrade1cost = 1;
public double $allupgrades;
public String version = "0.0.1";
;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    hasPlayed = sharedpreferences.getInt("hasPlayed", 1);
    sharedpreferences.getAll();

    if (hasPlayed == 1){
        $money = Double.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getString("money", (Double.toString($money))));
        $employercounter = Double.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getString("employercounter", (Double.toString($employercounter))));
        $employerupgrade1earnings = Double.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getString("employerupgrade1earnings", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1earnings))));
        $employerupgrade1level = Double.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getString("employerupgrade1level", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1level))));
        $employerupgrade1cost = Double.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getString("employerupgrade1cost", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1cost))));
        $employeeupgrade1level = Double.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getString("employeeupgrade1level", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1level))));
        $employeeupgrade1earnings = Double.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getString("employeeupgrade1earnings", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1earnings))));
        $employeeupgrade1cost = Double.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getString("employeeupgrade1cost", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1cost))));
    }
    if (hasPlayed == 0) {
        hasPlayed = 1;
        editor.putInt("hasPlayed", 1);
        editor.commit();
    }
    updatemoney();
    timer();

}
```

And here's my onStop/onPause (when I save the data)

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("money", (Double.toString($money)));
    editor.putString("employercounter", (Double.toString($employercounter)));
    editor.putString("employerupgrade1earnings", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1earnings )));
    editor.putString("employerupgrade1level", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1level)));
    editor.putString("employerupgrade1cost", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1cost)));
    editor.putString("employeeupgrade1level", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1level)));
    editor.putString("employeeupgrade1earnings", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1earnings)));
    editor.putString("employeeupgrade1cost", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1cost)));
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("money", (Double.toString($money)));
    editor.putString("employercounter", (Double.toString($employercounter)));
    editor.putString("employerupgrade1earnings", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1earnings )));
    editor.putString("employerupgrade1level", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1level)));
    editor.putString("employerupgrade1cost", (Double.toString($employerupgrade1cost)));
    editor.putString("employeeupgrade1level", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1level)));
    editor.putString("employeeupgrade1earnings", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1earnings)));
    editor.putString("employeeupgrade1cost", (Double.toString($employeeupgrade1cost)));
    editor.commit();
}
```

edit: im never going to learn why i'm being downvoted if i'm not told why i'm being downvoted. thanks

Comment: Case sensitivity: `savefile.getInt("hasplayed", 0);` doesn't match `editor.putInt("hasPlayed", 1);`

Comment: They're declared above it. Didn't include it to save space, sorry

Comment: Problem is you get sharedprefs same way to read and write, which is not correct, and shows lack of research... Then,... Downvotes came...

Comment: I looked at the shared preferences android dev page, and I couldn't understand. I've been looking at other questions here, and it seemed fine. And please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
SharedPreferences savefile = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with

```
SharedPreferences  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295347/5202007)

Comment: Also `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` will do the trick

Comment: Done what? Have you checked link?? Or you wait till solution comes by magic?

Comment: yes, i checked the link. infact i commented on it saying i had tried it before you posted this answer, so...

Comment: forgot to change onPause and onStop to this aswell. fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be because of this
`hasplayed` and `hasPlayed`, the key should be case sensitive

`savefile.getInt("hasplayed", 0);`

`editor.putInt("hasPlayed", 1);`

Comment: I've fixed that. It still isn't saving however.